# Glassfish filter init called multiple times

Tags: java, glassfish

I am using Glassfish 3.0.1 build 22 to run a custom webapp. For Authentication purposes I am using a custom Filter, which has an init() method:

```
public class MyFilter extends HttpServlet implements Filter

  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { ..// dostuff }
```

Normally the init() method is called once, at startup. Now I have a strange situation, the init() method is called several times. I cannot find an explanation for this.

What could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I am running Glassfish 3.1.1 build 12.

I had a `HttpServlet` on which Glassfish was calling `#init(ServletConfig)` on every request, perhaps similar to what you are experiencing.

Turns out I had overridded that method in my servlet but failed to call `super.init(servletConfig)`.  After adding the call to the superclass' method, Glassfish only called my `init` method once as expected.

I wonder why you are implementing `Filter` but extending `HttpServlet` ?  Is it possible you are not properly initializing the superclass and Glassfish somehow detects this and attempt to call init again?